# Can I use Sorbet without sig in source code?

Tags: sorbet

I would like to use Sorbet in my Ruby projects at work. As I want to make the process as smooth as possible, I'd like to know if it is possible to add static type checking only using RBI files in sorbet folder.
The idea is to avoid adding signatures to the source code, so my colleagues do not complain, then adding signatures in RBI on the side. This way I can start typing and benefiting in my local environment until it is advanced enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible for static checking but not for runtime checking. But I think it's enough for your use case